# What's wrongof the MyBatis SQL?

Tags: sql, mybatis

I've got two sql in MyBatis, the first one is a query result, and the second one tries to get the count of the first one.
the first sql:

```
<select id="getFeedbackEntities" resultType="map" parameterType="map">
        SELECT *  FROM feed_back
        WHERE (DATE(sumit_time) BETWEEN #{startDate} AND #{endDate})
        AND (comment LIKE #{keyword} OR city LIKE #{keyword} OR isp LIKE #{keyword})
    <if test="type > 0">
        AND type = #{type}
    </if>
    <if test="reason > 0">
        AND reason = #{reason}
    </if>
        ORDER BY #{sort} #{order} LIMIT #{offset}, #{limit}
</select>
```

the second sql is:

```
<select id="getFeedbackCount" resultType="int" parameterType="map">
        SELECT COUNT(1) FROM feed_back
        WHERE (DATE(sumit_time) BETWEEN #{startDate} AND #{endDate})
        AND (comment LIKE #{keyword} OR city LIKE #{keyword} OR isp LIKE #{keyword})
    <if test="type > 0">
        AND type = #{type}
    </if>
    <if test="reason > 0">
        AND reason = #{reason}
    </if>
</select>
```

I called them with the same parameters. The two sql work fine in seperate environment, while in the webapp, the second one got the wrong result. I'm really confused.

Comment: Are the final sql shown in the mybatis logs are as expected?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The logs show that the SQL and parameters are correct, but one of arguments for the second SQL is wrong. Problem solved, thanks!